# HierarchicalDataTemplate Binding not working

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, arcgis

I want to create a 2 level treview, with the root element of a string "Items":

```
-Items
   -item1
   -item2
   -...
```

I have 2 classes to achieve this: `ItemList, Item`. I call them with the property `CurrentItems`.

```
        private ItemList _currentItems = null;
        public ItemList CurrentItems
        {
            get
            {
                return _currentItems;
            }
            set
            {
                if(_currentItems!=value)
                {
                    SetProperty(ref _currentItems,
                    value, () => CurrentItems);
                }
            }
        }
```

`CurrentItems` is initialized by creating a temporary `ItemsList` which is then filled with Items:

```
    ItemList itemTempList = new ItemList();
    ...
    while(...)
    {
      Item item = new Item();
      ...
      itemTempList.Items.Add(item);
    }
    CurrentItems = itemTempList;
```

These are the two classes used:

```
    public class Item
    {
        public long ObjectID { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
    }

    public class ItemList : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private ObservableCollection<Item> items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
        public ObservableCollection<Item> Items
        {
            get
            {
                return items;
            }
            set
            {
                items = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<string> types = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        public ObservableCollection<string> Types
        {
            get
            {
                if(types.Count > 0)
                {
                    types.Add("Items");
                }
                return types;
            }
            set
            {
                types = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }


        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }

    }
```

The View is initialized with a constructor:

```
        public ItemView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

And finally, this is the xaml:

```
         <TreeView  Name="itemTree" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" SelectedItemChanged="itemTree_SelectedItemChanged"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentItems}">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
                </Style>
            </TreeView.Resources>
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Items,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <Label Content="{Binding Types,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}">
                                <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                                    <ContextMenu>
                                        <MenuItem Header="Duplicate" Click="DuplicateCell"/>
                                        <MenuItem Header="Delete" Click="DeleteCell"/>
                                    </ContextMenu>
                                </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
```

With my current understanding and code I am not able to create the TreeView.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Ash yes sorry, my bad. But this doesn't fix the issue

Comment: binding in general and `ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentItems}"` specifically will work only if you set correct DataContext. do you set view DataContext anywhere? also check Visua Studio Output window fr any binding errors

Comment: @ASh Yes, DataContext is changed but only when interacting with TreeView items. I checked VS but there seem to be no binding problems. When I use Debug, the ```Items``` are never returned to be shown in UI.

Comment: try `ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentItems.Items}"`

Comment: @ASh Sadly, still not working

Comment: @ASh I figured it out! Acoring to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource#remarks certain interfaces need to be implemented in order for the treeview to show its elements. My ```CurentItems``` did not implement such an interface.

Comment: you can post your own solution as an answer. the question is about wpf, the link refers to uwp. in wpf ItemsSource has to be IEnumerable. ObservableCollection fulfils that requirement.